# API with CORS enabled doesn't work with Angular 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angular

I'm using the API of Ice and Fire at [this link](https://anapioficeandfire.com) and I only receive some headers, instead of the full response headers. I confirmed in the GitHub repository that the API has CORS enabled, for all origins and all headers.

```
private static void EnableCrossSiteRequests(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "GET,HEAD");
    config.EnableCors(cors);
}
```

So I would expect the API to return all headers. Instead, Safari picks them up all of the time, when I disable the cache. This is also weird, right? Now, I know that the API has caching set up, could that be of any problem?

Angular actually *never* picks up on the right headers, while Safari does sometimes. Who can help me out here?